# How can I get the specific bucket a value belongs to in a cumulative histogram?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am quite new to PromQL. Given a metric which measures the latency of a service like this -

```
samplemetric_bucket{le=“125”} 2
samplemetric_bucket{le=“250”} 6
samplemetric_bucket{le=“500”} 10
samplemetric_bucket{le=“1000} 15
samplemetric_bucket{le="+Inf"} 20
```

I have a problem statement where I’m given a threshold such as 300 and an alert is triggered when a value exceeds it. What I have done so far is that, since I know which one is the starting bucket it will belong to, I have created a regular expression to get me the list of all buckets where le > 500. I have created an RE cause this value is a string.
So the current PromQl query looks like this -

```
increase(samplemetric_bucket{le=~"[5-9][0-9]{2,}.0|[1-9][0-9]{3,}|.*Inf*.”}[10m]))
```

Given that I get an entry where the metric value exceeds 300, the output at that point would look something like this -

```
{le=500}  1
{le=1000} 1
{le=+Inf} 1
```

Since this cumulative, the logic to trigger an alert here becomes redundant. So in the place where I ideally need to get `{le=500} 1` I get three different values.

Is there any other way I can get the minimum of the le values in PromQL. What other approaches I could take?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an estimated share of samples, which exceed some threshold, then try the following query:

```
1 - histogram_share(300, increase(samplemetric_bucket[1h]))
```

It returns the share of samples stored in `samplemetric` [histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) with values higher than 300 over the last hour.

This query uses [histogram_share()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share) function. Unfortunately this function isn't supported by Prometheus yet. It is available in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on.

Comment: Thank you but I needed a query specific to Prometheus.